# redux useSelector: component is not reactive to state updates

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am setting up a very basic react typescript and redux app.
I used useSelector() to retrieve state then use it in my component.
however when I dipatch to the store adding a new article the ui doesn't change, I checked redux dev tools and the store is updated, I read that useSelector automatically subscribes to store so I'm not sure why I'm having this problem.
my App component code:

```
function App() {
  const dispatch: Dispatch<any> = useDispatch();

  const articles: readonly IArticle[] = useSelector(
    (state: ArticleState) => state.articles
  );

  const saveArticle = React.useCallback(
    (article: IArticle) => dispatch(addArticle(article)),
    [dispatch]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>My Articles</h1>
        <AddArticle saveArticle={saveArticle} />
        <ul>
          {articles.map((article: IArticle) => (
            <li>{article.title}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the addArticle ActionCreator

```
export function addArticle(article: IArticle) {
  const action: ArticleAction = {
    type: actionTypes.ADD_ARTICLE,
    article,
  };

  return simulateHttpRequest(action);
}
```

### The Reducer

```
const reducer = (
  state: ArticleState = initialState,
  action: ArticleAction
): ArticleState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ADD_ARTICLE:
      const newState = {
        ...state,
      };
      const newArticle: IArticle = {
        id: Math.random(), // not really unique
        title: action.article.title,
        body: action.article.body,
      };
      newState.articles.push(newArticle);
      return newState;
    case actionTypes.REMOVE_ARTICLE:
      const newArticles = state.articles.filter(
        (article) => article.id !== action.article.id
      );
      return {
        ...state,
        articles: newArticles,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

here's a screenshot I see that data is actually updating in the store

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code that "adds" the item to the articles? useSelector wont fire if the instance of the state has not changed.

Comment: also why are you marking the value as "readonly"?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro the code to add a new article is the saveArticle method

Comment: no it is not... the function that saves the article is dispatch(addArticle(article)... so we need to see the code for "addArticle"

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I just edited the question and added the addArticle actionCreator

Comment: i still dont see where the state is being modified. it seems to me that a new instance of the state is not being created and that is why the useSelector is not firing.  the redux team recently added a change to react-redux that useSelectors only fire if "state" is a new instance al together... this is called immutability

Comment: Can you show the actual reducer that is supposed to handle the `ADD_ARTICLE` action type?  Also, as a side note: it looks like you're writing a very outdated style of Redux code there. "Modern Redux" with our official Redux Toolkit package eliminates the need to write _any_ action creators by hand, and it works great with TS:  https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/overview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `newState.articles.push(newArticle);` is mutating the existing `articles` array. Your selector is then trying to read `state.articles`. Since it's the *same reference* as before, React-Redux assumes nothing has changed, and will not re-render:

https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#equality-comparisons-and-updates

Please switch over to using Redux Toolkit for your store setup and reducer logic.  Not only will it let you simplify your reducers by writing this kind of "mutating" logic and letting it create updates immutably, it effectively makes accidental mutations like this impossible.